# Is this an Oak Tree?

Tags: identification, trees

I've got this tree down in my back yard and I cannot figure out what type it is. The bark looks like Oak but the leaves I'm not sure about. There have been no nuts/acorns drop from it that have been noticeable the past year.

Any idea?

[image: Up Close Bark]

[image: Up Close Leaves]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*[Liriodentron tulipifera](http://www.na.fs.fed.us/pubs/silvics_manual/volume_2/liriodendron/tulipifera.htm)*  - Tulip poplar, yellow poplar among other names.

Answer (score 4):

Check it for flowers in the spring. Looks like a Tuliptree (aka yellow poplar)

Answer (score 4):

I agree that it's a [Liriodendron tulipfera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liriodendron_tulipifera). The picture on the [left](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=a878) shows the leaves and the bark. On the [right](http://greatplainsnursery.com/product/tuliptree-2/), you can see its lovely flower.

Interestingly, even though it's frequently called yellow poplar or tulip poplar, it actually belongs to the [magnolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnoliaceae), not the [poplar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Populus), family.

*Click on pictures for larger view.*

[image]
[image]

Comment: vote for mentioning that it is a magnolia